# VB.NET VScrollBar, Reverse Functionality

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar, reverse

I'm looking to reverse the functionality of a VScrollBar in VB.NET - I would like the number to increase when the up button is pressed and decrease when the down button is pressed.

I'm surprised that this issue isn't more commonly represented online, but I could find nothing online about making a VScrollBar work the way I want it to in VB.NET. Apparently in VB 6.0, you were able to flip the Min and Max values and this achieved what I desire to do, but they removed that feature in VB.NET. Anyone have an idea of how this might be achieved? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The "number?" As in the scroll bar's position, or just a value?

Comment: I have the size of the VScrollBar to the point where the scrollbar itself isn't visible, so I am referring specifically to the value that is returned.

Comment: Kinda simple, use Maximum - Value (assuming Minimum = 0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to reverse a value, scroll bar or not:

```
Dim reversedValue As Integer = maximumValue - actualValue
```

If you need a minimum, that's okay too:

```
Dim reversedValue As Integer = minimumValue + maximumValue - actualValue
```

Comment: If my minimum value is 1 and my maximum value is 1000, and if my actual value is 5, then 1+1000-5=996. After it changes the value, it works properly, but it starts at 1 and jumps to 1000 upon incrementing. Am I not applying this formula correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to post that first comment. *laugh*

Comment: txtQuantity.Text = (vsbQuantity.Minimum + vsbQuantity.Maximum - reverseValue).ToString()

Comment: @ToddBauer: `reverseValue` there might need to be `yourVSB.Value`, but I can't see anything else wrong there... so the actual value is jumping. Is your `Increment` property changed? Are they *too* close together? (Come to think of it, you might be better of with a `NumericUpDown`...)

Comment: Oops, I apologize - I didn't paste it, but I'm doing the same operation to vsbQuantity.Value as I do to txtQuantity.Text. However, all that is moot, because NumericUpDown accomplishes exactly what I need done! Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `minimum = -1000` and `maximum = 0` .
Then `Result = VScrollbar.Value * -1`.
Now direction is from down to up.